# Child Component is not able to trigger state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Simple React State Example. The parent component is App which starts out just showing a button, when the button is clicked it should render `AllRecipes` (this works and I am able to manage state of AllRecipes). Inside `AllRecipes` is a button which needs to trigger a state change to then further render `ingredients` (this button does nothing when clicked, it needs to toggle the state of ingredients). I think this is a really good small example of how to manage state but I am missing something..

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {showIngredients: false, showRecipes: false};
    },

    toggleRecipes: function(){
        this.setState({showRecipes: !this.state.showRecipes})
    },

    toggleIngredients: function(){
        this.setState({showRecipes: !this.state.showRecipes})
    },

  render: function() {
        var recipes = this.state.showRecipes ? <Recipes/> : null;
        return (
                <div>
                    <h1> Recipe App </h1>
                        <button onClick={this.toggleRecipes}> Show Recipes </button>

                        {recipes}
                </div>
            );
    }
});

var Recipes = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var ingredients = this.props.showIngredients ? <Ingredients/> : null;
        return (
                <div>
                    <h1> list of recipes </h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li> Chicken Soup </li>
                            <li> Chicken Wings </li>
                            <button onClick={this.props.toggleIngredients}> Show Recipes </button>
                            {ingredients}
                        </ul>
                </div>

            );
    }
});

var Ingredients = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <h1> List of Ingredients </h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li> Salt </li>
                            <li> Pepper </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            );
    }
});

React.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

Comment: Essentially the Recipes Component simply can not see the toggleIngredients function in the parent component `app`. Did I design the flow incorrectly, or am I missing something small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't passing `toggleIngredients` to `Recipes`. Try changing

```
var recipes = this.state.showRecipes ? <Recipes/> : null;
```

to

```
var recipes = this.state.showRecipes ? <Recipes toggleIngredients={this.toggleIngredients} /> : null;
```

Comment: Yes I think that is definitely where I am going wrong! I am getting this error `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string` Do you have a syntax error in your posting or something?

Comment: Should it be something like this?
`<Recipes toggleIngredients="{this.toggleIngredients}" /> `

Comment: yes, that looks right (and similar to what I posted, but with the correct method name - sorry ;).

Comment: ah, it shouldnt be quoted... updating answer